# How to programatically save a query results to a text file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

SQL Server 2005 - How can I save the results of a query to a text file programatically? (i.e without choosing the Results to file option in Analyzer and not through sql command)?

For example

```
select * from northwind.dbo.suppliers
```

And I save my results to CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

in language of your choice

```
Open a SQL Connection
Issue command (select)
While not end_of_results
  for each column
    write column value
    write ','
  write new line
Clean up connection
```